# Numerically evaluating functions in the limit $\to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Looking for some pointers as to the rules around numerically evaluating a function in the limit e.g.

$$
f(x) = \lim_{y\to0} g(x,y) / h(y)
$$
I have seen methods where, for a series of fixed values of $x$, $g$ is plotted against $h$ for a range of $y$ followed by a linear least-squares fit and the gradient of the line is taken as the value of $f(x)$ at each $x$.

My questions are

Firstly, is this a generally correct method for any functions $g$ and $h$?

Secondly, what if the relationship between g and h is not linear - is it ok to fit a a polynomial for example?

Another example:

obtain the value of $g(y)$ where: $f(x,y) \sim x^{g(y)} \lim_{x\to 0}$

I have seen this solved by fixing y and then plotting $\log(f)$ against $\log(x)$ for a range of $x$ and taking the gradient of a straight line fit as the value of $g(y)$. Confusingly I have also seen the value of $g(y)$ taken as the gradient $-1$.

I have not found a good introduction to the rules of numerically evaluating the limits of functions and would appreciate some hints.

Thanks

Comment: I reformatted your question. Please check and make sure that I didn't change what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve the problem for *any* functions $f$ and $g$. At least, you have to know that the limit exists, for example require that the functions are [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Relationship_to_continuity) in $y$ at $0$, or better on some neighbor of $0$.

Could you be more specific about your functions? Unless we know something about them, it's basically impossible to give a reasonable solution that correctly approximates the limit.

You could always use standard tools how to compute the limit exactly. If this is possible, you'll get far more precise result (and faster). Assuming the functions are continuous:

1. If $h(0)$ is non-zero then you can simply evaluate the expression at 0.
2. If $h(0)=0$ and $g(x,0)\neq 0$ then the limit diverges.
3. If $h(0)=g(x,0)=0$ and the functions are differentiable at $0$ in $y$, use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). This will convert your limit into another one, which very often has a non-zero denominator (if it doesn't, you can try to use the rule again).